# How to run html with dart in My Flutter project?

Tags: html, flutter, web

I want to build a flutter project and call app and web plaform native code
I have completed Android code but have no idea how to achieve web platform
I found many solution recommend [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but this library just support Android and iOS, not for web

My html folder:

[image]

Go to different platform:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      Route route = WebScreen.getRoute();
      Navigator.push(context, route);
    } else {
      channel.invokeMethod('showMessage', <String, String>{ 
        'message': 'This is a Toast from From Flutter to Android Native Code Yes, It is working'
      });
    }
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
)
```

WebScreen:

```dart
class WebScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  WebScreen({super.key});

  late WebViewController _controller;

  static Route getRoute() {
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  WebScreen());
    return route;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller = WebViewController()
    ..loadFlutterAsset('assets/help.html');

    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You should probably not call loadFlutterAsset inside the build method. Extract it into initState.